# Running python package with system() from C program returns error

Tags: python, c, linux, clion

I plan to use the checkov python package for generating reports of helm charts and then read the output, all with a C program. However, when I try to run the package with system(), I get an error: `sh: 1: checkov: not found`

I can use the command from the terminal simply as `checkov` and it works. Python is on path, and so are the packages.

The complete command I use in my c program is:

```
system("checkov -d /workspace/testdir -o json");
```

I have tried using `python3.8 -m`, but that also returns an error since this checkov is not a script.

How do I fix this issue? I am running this on Ubuntu 20.04, with Python3.8.

**Edit:** Following @fukanchik's suggestion, I used system("ps $$") to check the shells and system("$PATH") for the paths. It turns out that the c program was using sh, while my default terminal is bash. Moreover, the `/home/epodegrid/.local/bin` is not on path for sh, causing the error. When I output the PATH for bash using system() in the C program, the path is missing too. So how do I fix this?

**Edit 2 :** Upon even more review, it seems that the path is added and works fine when I compile the cmake program in the Ubuntu terminal, but does not work with clion's run/build option.

**Edit 3:** [NOT DUPLICATE QUESTION] The problem is with Clion not setting environment variables for the terminal, even though the program is compiled with WSL Ubuntu 20.04. In the Ubuntu terminal, the paths are set correctly, however, when I run system() with Clion's tools, the paths are not set.

Comment: Try `system("bash -c \"checkov -d /workspace/testdir -o json\"")` if that won't work make sure `$PATH` in your terminal is the same as the $PATH available to your problem when it runs.

Comment: @Oka, the `ls -l /bin/sh` did not tell the difference between terminals and with `ps $$` I noticed that the shells are indeed difference. The paths are also missing in sh which C is using. I've added this as an edit, in the question.

Comment: @fukanchik I tried `system("bash -c \"$PATH\"")` and it differs in the C program as compared to the one in my terminal. I've added more on this in the question as edit.

Comment: Fix the `PATH` _before_ running your C program. This is a common FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the whole pathname to `checkof` in order to see it it is a problem of paths.

Comment: It is not an issue with checkov but something with the shell spawned from the c code not recognizing checkov. The path to the test directory and the system paths are fine, even after testing with the code by @Oka as mentioned above.